# Reading/writing to Google Storage from Google Compute Windows 2008 VM

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I have a Google Compute VM (LAMP) webserver set up to copy files to a Google Storage Bucket, which then need to be accessed (read and write) by a program on a Google Compute VM (Windows 2008). I can't seem to find any documentation about how a Google Compute Engine Windows VM can access storage buckets.

Is there a way this is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing, but not with a windows VM, but I think the principle is the same.

First you need to allow Project Access for your VM from the Google Cloud Console https://console.developers.google.com/project, see the screenshot below:

[image]

Once you've done this you need to call the metadata server to get an access token from your program. You need to make a HTTP call to the metadata server, here is an example from the docs (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication) using curl, bear in mind when programming this you need to also provide the header **"Metadata-Flavor: Google"**:

> $ curl "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" \
>     -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"

```
{
  "access_token":"ya29.AHES6ZRN3-HlhAPya30GnW_bHSb_QtAS08i85nHq39HE3C2LTrCARA",
  "expires_in":3599,
  "token_type":"Bearer"
}
```

You obviously need to code this HTTP call and the parsing of the JSON data in whichever programming language you are using for your program and extract the **"access_token"**, based on the **"expires_in"** field you might also need to implement a mechanism to fetch a new token once it expires. You can then use the Google supplied cloud storage client library (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/libraries) for your programming language and use the access token above for authenticating calls to cloud storage. I use Java and the Cloud storage class in the API library has this method that can be used:

> .setOauthToken("blah")

Comment: Development on the program I am needing to run has ceased, and will sadly never be updated to provide this authentication. A solution I have found is to use a restricted samba share on the webserver and the Windows VM instances map to that. Not pretty, and requires some additional file shuffling, but I think seems the only way. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the drive with [CloudBerry](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/map-google-cloud-storage-network-drive.aspx). I would like to find a better way to do it though using only Google Cloud. Please let me know if you find anything better.